# Exceptions when invoking email composer in WP8 and the App crashes

Tags: email, cordova, windows-phone-8

Iam developing an App for WP8 in which the application is getting crashed while invoking email composer.

**The thread 0x40 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in Microsoft.Phone.ni.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll**

Am using **de.appplant.cordova.plugin.email-composer** plugin to invoke email composer. Please help me out.

Comment: Can you post some of your code? In where you are getting exception actually?

Comment: I found the reason for this issue. When sending email am giving some data as inline html which  exceeds the limit of gmail composer. Due to this the app was crashing.

Comment: Thats good :) Post this as an answer!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason for this issue. When sending email am giving some data as inline html which exceeds the limit of gmail composer. Due to this the app was crashing.